# Error message when running a T-Test in R due to character variable

Tags: r, t-test

I have been trying to run a two side t-test in R but keep running into error. Below is my process flow, dataset details and script from R-studio.
I used a dataset called LungCapacity that I downloaded from this website: https://www.statslectures.com/r-scripts-datasets.

```
#Imported data set into RStudio.

# Ran a summary report to see the data and class.
summary(LungCapData)

# Here I could see that the smoke column is a character, so I converted it to a factor
LungCapacityData$Smoke <- factor(LungCapacityData$Smoke)

# On checking the summary. I see its converted to a factor with a yes and no.

# I want to run a t-test between lung capacity and smoking. 
t.test(LungCapData$LungCap, LungCapData$Smoke, alternative = c("two.sided"), mu=0, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, paired = FALSE)
```

Now on running this I get the following error.

```
Error in var(y) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I have tried to convert the smoke variable from Yes and No to 1 and 0. The data runs but is not correct. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you conclude that `t.test()` run on factors converted to numeric returns incorrect result?

Comment: Check spelling.

Answer (score 3):

You're very close, you just need to call `t.test` with a formula:

```
LungCapacityData <- read.table(
  "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0BxQfpNgXuWoITmVwQzJ2VF9qVlU&export=download",
  header = TRUE)

t.test(LungCap ~ Smoke, data = LungCapacityData,
       alternative = c("two.sided"), mu=0, var.equal = FALSE,
       conf.level = 0.95, paired = FALSE)

#   Welch Two Sample t-test
#
#data:  LungCap by Smoke
#t = -3.6498, df = 117.72, p-value = 0.0003927
#alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# -1.3501778 -0.4003548
#sample estimates:
# mean in group no mean in group yes 
#         7.770188          8.645455
```

With your current approach, you're trying to compare `LungCapacityData$LungCap` which is a numeric vector:

```
LungCapacityData$LungCap[1:10]
# [1]  6.475 10.125  9.550 11.125  4.800  6.225  4.950  7.325  8.875  6.800
```

With `LungCapacityData$Smoke`, which is a vector of factors:

```
LungCapacityData$Smoke[1:10]
# [1] no  yes no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no
```

Instead, you want to instruct `t.test` to compare `LungCapacityData$LungCap` when grouping by `LungCapacityData$Smoke`. That is achieved with a formula.

The formula `LungCap ~ Smoke` says that `LungCap` should depend on `Smoke`. When you use a formula, you also need to supply `data =`.

When you try to convert `LungCapacityData$Smoke` to numeric, you get the wrong result because you're just getting the factor level indices which have no biological significance.

```
as.numeric(LungCapacityData$Smoke)[1:10]
# [1] 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

You're basically asking if the mean of the factor levels we assigned is different than the mean of lung capacity.

The other way is to subset `LungCapacityData$LungCap` yourself, but that's a lot more typing:

```
t.test(LungCapacityData$LungCap[LungCapacityData$Smoke == "yes"],
       LungCapacityData$LungCap[LungCapacityData$Smoke == "no"],
       alternative = c("two.sided"), mu=0, var.equal = FALSE,
       conf.level = 0.95, paired = FALSE)
```

Comment: Check spelling of dataframes.

Comment: Ha, thanks, yeah, the OP used both, so I just made two copies. I'll edit to be more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the OP, `t.test()` attempts to compare the means of two vectors, so the `t.test()` function expects them both to be numeric.

Instead, use the formula version of `t.test()`. With this method, `t.test()` uses the column on the right side of the `~` as the grouping variable, and the column on the left side of the `~` as the numeric variable whose means are to be compared across the two groups for the other variable.

```
data <- read.table(file = "./data/LungCapData.txt",header = TRUE)
t.test(LungCap ~ Smoke,data = data)
```

...and the output:

```
> t.test(LungCap ~ Smoke,data = data)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  LungCap by Smoke
t = -3.6498, df = 117.72, p-value = 0.0003927
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.3501778 -0.4003548
sample estimates:
 mean in group no mean in group yes 
         7.770188          8.645455 

>
```